# How can I tell if "find my iPhone" has been used

Tags: iphone, icloud

We have several apple devices at home. If we track any one of them, using "find me iPhone" does it log or message the iCloud user that it has been tracked? Example: If I did find a find my iPhone on my mother's account or she did it to mine, would either of us know?

Also, if I turn off my location services, does that prevent me and anyone else tracking my iPhone?

Comment: If its been tracked (ie. only look at location): no. 
BUT...
If an action has been used (eg. play sound): yes - it will email the apple ID owner

Answer (score 3):

No, simply using Find My iPhone to find the location of the phone doesn't record the action anywhere.

Turning off location services will mean that Find My iPhone won't be able to obtain the location, unless Lost Mode is activated.

> In iOS 7, if you turn off Location Services and use Find My iPhone Lost Mode, Location Services will be re-enabled on the device as long as the device is in Lost Mode.

<sup>Source: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5594</sup>